# My program crashes when calling a function in c++

Tags: c++

so i have to make three functions.One asks for how many employees are in a company.The other asks how many days they missed.The third one calculates the average by dividing the amount of employees by the number of days missing.In main,all i have to do is have cout prompts and call the functions.Im not to sure if i'm doing it right,but it crashes when it has to calculate the average.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int employee(int employeeNum);
int missingDays(int daysMissing);
double getAvg(int employeeNum,int daysMissing,double average);

int employee(int employeeNum)
{
  cout<<"Enter the number of employee in the company.";
  cin>>employeeNum;
  return employeeNum;
}

int missingDays(int daysMissing)
{
  cout<<"Enter the amount of days employees missed during the past year.";
  cin>>daysMissing;
  return daysMissing;
}

double getAvg(int employeeNum,int daysMissing,double average)
{
  average=employeeNum/daysMissing;
  return average;
}

int main()
{
  int employeeNum,people,missing,daysMissing;
  double avg,average;

  people=employee(employeeNum);
  cout<<"The number of employees in the company is "<<people<<"."<<endl;

  missing=missingDays(daysMissing);
  cout<<"The number of days employees missed during the past year is "<<missing<<".";

  avg=getAvg(employeeNum,daysMissing,average);
  cout<<average;
}
```

Let me know what i got to do and thanks for the help.

Comment: Does it crash if daysMissing is 0? Otherwise add more infos

Comment: As Vlad pointed out, it should crash if daysMissing is 0. You probably want to return 0 if daysMissing is 0, and otherwise calculate the average.

Comment: if you could indent your code, that's be great :)

Comment: Why are you passing in (by value) employeeNum, daysMissing and average when these are calculated in the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So depending on compiler the value of `daysMissing` is either undefined or initialized with `0`.

In your function `getAvg` you divide `employeeNum/daysMissing;`

But you are not allowed to divide by zero, thats's it :)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like homework, so you should only expect nudges.  So, some nudges: why do your functions `employee()` and `missingDays()` take arguments?  And why does `getAvg()` take 3?  In which variables do your input values end up?  Where are they used next (if at all)?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line

```
missing=missingDays(daysMissing);
```

for some reason you have two variables for "daysMissing" (I'm not sure why you pass it in to your missingDays function in the first place)

After that line, `missing` will contain the value input, not `daysMissing` (since it's not passed by reference)

Your getAvg function, presumably, is crashing with a division by zero error.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int employee(int employeeNum);
int missingDays(int daysMissing);
double getAvg(int employeeNum,int daysMissing,double average);

int employee(int employeeNum)
{
  cout<<"Enter the number of employee in the company: ";
  cin>>employeeNum;
  return employeeNum;
}

int missingDays(int daysMissing)
{
  cout<<"Enter the amount of days employees missed during the past year: ";
  cin>>daysMissing;
  return daysMissing;
}

double getAvg(int employeeNum,int daysMissing)
{
    if(daysMissing == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
  return (double)employeeNum/daysMissing;;
}

int main()
{
  int employeeNum,people,missing,daysMissing;
  double avg,average;

  people=employee(employeeNum);
  cout<<"The number of employees in the company is: "<<people<<"\n";

  missing=missingDays(daysMissing);
  cout<<"The number of days employees missed during the past year is: "<<missing<<"\n";

  avg=getAvg(people,missing);
  cout<<avg;
}
```